# Express a permutation as a product of the generators

Tags: group-theory

So i am asked to write a permutation as a product of generators, I've turned the permutation into a product of disjoint cycles : $(125)(3467)$

I'm asked to use the generators: $w_1= (12)$, $w_2 = (13)$....$w_7 = (17)$

I know i can write the first cycle out as $(15)(12)$, but not sure how to write the second cycle out using the same generators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Note that $(1,i)(1,j)(1,i) = (i,j)$ and $(1,2,5)(3,4,6,7) = (1,2)(1,5)(3,4)(3,6)(3,7)$.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the fact that $(1,i_1)(1,i_2)\ldots(1,i_n)(1,i_1) = (i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n)$.